# Angular 6. Is it possible to inject service by condition?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-dependency-injection

In my angular app (with the angular material) I have a filter panel and I want besides select to be able to make autocomplete (user input value and it sends to the back-end, whereby $regexp query we find the match in MongoDB collection). But to do it I need manually inject service into filters component. I didn't find any info on how to do it.

I need something like this:

```
if (filters.serviceName) {
  injector.inject(serviceName);
}

injector.get(serviceName).find(searchQuery);
```

Is it possible? Thanks.

Comment: Which version of angular are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 6.1

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes you can `inject` service dynamically using [injector.get()](https://angular.io/api/core/Injector#get)

Sample code :

```
import { Component, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { MyService } from './my.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  myService : MyService;

  constructor(private injector : Injector){
    if(true){ // some condition
      this.myService = injector.get<MyService>(MyService);
    }

    console.log(this.myService.prop1)
  }
}
```

Working [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-service-injection?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Hi Amit, Is it possible to do it on the root, we have environment specific services.

Comment: What do you mean by root? AppComponent? If so, yes. Above example does the same.

Answer (score 2):

Another variant use `@Inject` decorator, if condition compute outside current class.

```
export interface IService {
  test: string;
}


@Injectable()
export class Serivce1 implements IService {
  test: 'service1';
}

@Injectable()
export class Serivce2 implements IService {
  test: 'service2';
}

const CONDITION = Math.random() > 0.5;
    
@Component({
   selector: 'my-app',
   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
   name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;
    
   constructor(@Inject(CONDITION ? Serivce1 : Serivce2) private service: IService) {
        console.warn(service);
   }
}
```